# Android, увеличения ImageView в recycleWiew по тапу, алгоритм

Tags: android, android-imageview

Недавно начал изучать Android. Дошёл до recycleWiew. Столкнулся с необходимостью открыть imageView из ячейки полноэкранном режиме по нажатию на него.

Сейчас я делаю так:

**onBindViewHolder**

```
Glide.with(context).load(new File(path + "/" + galleryList.get(i))).into(viewHolder.img);
```

А в **cell.xml**
я использовал разные другие библиотеки, но добился только того что по тапу приложение масштабировалось в рамках ячейки. Попытки прорвать границы ухищрениями типо adjustViewBounds не помогли.

Сейчас мне кажется что ошибка где - то в подходе. Подскажите, как сделать правильно?

Заранее спасибо.

Upd:

Попробовал по совету Jarvis_J в комментарии, но натыкаюсь на NPE при попытке присвоить imageView изображение.

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/imagegallery"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="60dp"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/scaledImage"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Я так понял что этот imageView не нужно инициализировать в конструкторе ViewHolder, это ведь общей для всех элемент, просто с разным наполнением. Поэтому я просто написал:

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    ...
    ImageView scaledImg;
    ...
```

...

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final Adapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
            ...
            scaledImg.findViewById(R.id.scaledImage);
            final File n = new File(path + itemLlist.get(i));
            scaledImg.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(n));
            ...
```

...

```
viewHolder.img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!isScaled) {
                    scaledImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    isScaled = !isScaled;
                }
            }
```

Где я ошибаюсь?

Comment: ImageView инициализируйте не в адаптере RV. А в самой активити

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш `ImageView` в любом случае будет ограничен родителем - (ячейкой) `RecyclerView`. Если вы хотите сделать изображение на весь экран - вам нужен другой `ImageView`, который будет размером с корневой layout.

Например, так:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/scaledImage"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

По нажатию делайте этот `ImageView` видимым (`setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`) и устанавливайте ему картинку из ячейки `recyclerView` (`setImageResource(...)`).

По нажатию на увеличенное изображение вновь скрывайте его (`setVisibility(View.GONE)`).

Answer (score 5):

Можно это сделать с красивой анимацией открытия. Использовать для этого две активити. Первая с RecyclerView (RvActivity назовем), а вторая просто с imageView (IvActivity).

RvActivity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

IvActivity:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            android:transitionName="imageTag" //указываем тег для анимирования перехода

/>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

По клику на элемент RecyclerView делаем старт активити из RvActivity (пример на `Kotlin`):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            startActivity(Intent(this, IvActivity::class.java),
                    ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this,
                            rv,"imageTag")
                            .toBundle())
        } else {
            startActivity(Intent(this, IvActivity::class.java))
        }
```

На `Java` будет что-то типо того (пишу без теста, по памяти. Давно джавку не юзал):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, IvActivity.class),
                ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this,
                        findViewById(R.id.rv),"imageTag")
                        .toBundle());
    } else {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, IvActivity.class));
    }
```

Ну и соответственно в IvActivity в ImageView установите ту картинку по которой кликнули (передать информацию о адресе кликнутой картинки можно через Intent)